# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when reasigning GKGridGraph

Tags: objective-c, gameplay-kit

I have a graph like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) GKGridGraph *graph;
```

Assgin it with width and height:

```
 self.graph = [[GKGridGraph alloc] initFromGridStartingAt:(vector_int2){0, 0}
                                                    width:38
                                                   height:8
                                         diagonalsAllowed:NO];
```

And later I need to reasign self.graph with new width and height, so I do the same as above. And by doing so I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

I tried creating new graph and assigning it to self.graph and still get the same.

Comment: Quite possibly this is a bug in GameplayKit itself. Be sure to note which version(s) of OS X or iOS you're running it on when you [file a bug with Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: I am also having the same exception when re-assigning a new grid graph, this time in Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem using swift and 9.2 as the target. I reverted to 9.0 as the target and the problem went away. So I'm guessing that it is a bug.

Comment: I can reproduce the bug in swift and submitted a playground example to Apple. The bug appears to occur when a node is removed from the graph and then a new graph is assigned to the variable holding the original graph.